# Django site hosting on Heroku "No web processes runnng"

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

So I tried to host my Django application to Heroku and at first it worked. Then I wanted to add some release commands so I did this:

release_commands.sh

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

And in my Procfile:

```
release: bash ./release_commands.sh
web: gunicorn todo.wsgi --log-file -
```

The second line in my Procfile is unchanged, so I guessed that the error must be coming from the release commands, but that's not the case as in my heroku logs I have this:

```
2021-02-17T19:41:31.675215+00:00 heroku[release.6232]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-17T19:41:31.772693+00:00 heroku[release.6232]: State changed from up to complete
2021-02-17T19:41:34.021990+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user georgi.hr.dim@gmail.com
```

This is the error message:

```
2021-02-17T19:41:43.594322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=essentialtodo.herokuapp.com request_id=5dce4816-6343-44c3-9c8f
-171e79379abc fwd="78.90.0.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out what the problem was. For some reason after adding the release commands my dynos were turned off. To fix this: go to your heroku app (on the heroku website) -> go to resources -> press the edit button on your dyno -> turn it on and confirm
.